# VPN с модема на выделенку

Tags: vpn, debian, linux

Доброго времени суток.

Есть VPN к биллингу. Работает через 3G модем. Подключили выделенку.Надо ли перенастраивать VPN для работы по выделенному каналу?И что перенастраивать?

OS debian squeeze

Answer (score 1):

Я не вижу смысла что то перенастраивать, VPN работает поверх физического подключения. В твоем случае поменялось только физическое подключение к сети, логическое (VPN) осталось такое же.